# interpolating a '#' in a rails url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a a webpage which has different tabs. The tabs used to be different pages, but now through angularjs they are effectively a 'single-page' with no loading between each clicked tab.

So every URL has a '#'

```
marshcentre#/page/77 
marshcentre#/news
marshcentre#/promotion
```

However, when I select the 'contact us' page I get a URL like this

```
marshcentre/contactus
```

which is fine because it is a form that needs submitting. but once on this page, returning to the other tabs is without the single page effect so links are now like

```
marshcentre/page/77
```

without the hash.

Is there a way to append the hash to links? I am not sure how else to solve this

```
=active_link_to "Overview", centre_path(sensitive_venue), active: :exclusive, class_active: "active", class: "inner_container"
```

here is an example link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would use the `:anchor` option to the path helper in a link_to, redirect_to etc:

```
link_to "My Text", foo_path(foo, :anchor => "myanchor")
#=> <a href="/foos/123#myanchor">My Text</a>
```

Note that :anchor is an argument to the path helper (ie foo_path in this case), rather than to link_to

Comment: thanks I saw that, but the anchor can't be at the end of the url, it needs to be in the middle

Comment: Everything after the # is the anchor, so by definition it's at the end.  So in your case the anchor would be `/page/77`

Comment: I think your link_to probably needs to look something like this: `link_to "Contact Us", root_path(:anchor => page_path(page))` (this assumes you've got a route called 'root' which goes to `/` - replace it with "home_path" or whatever else it's called in your app, if you need to.  I'm also assuming you've got a variable `page` which points to a Page object.